# Decimal field rounding in WTForms

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form that contains a price decimal field, like so:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import wtforms
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from decimal import ROUND_HALF_UP

class AddListingBase(Form):
    title = wtforms.StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    details = wtforms.TextAreaField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    price = wtforms.DecimalField(places=2, rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

When I submit the form, the decimal value is suppoosed to be rounded to 2 decimal places, but that never happens. I always get the value as it was specified (e.g. 99.853 is 99.853, not 99.85 as it should be).

Comment: I had a look at the code at https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/1ea78bbe2668b17c9dbb1c195c89e02a26666483/wtforms/fields/core.py#L621-L654, the parameters only applied to values *supplied* to be used as starting values (_values function), and not for input (_process_formdata function). So you'll have to roll your own validator.

Comment: @mueslo that is the answer, so add it as one!

Answer (score 8):

As @mueslo has rightly inferred, this is because the default `DecimalField` implementation does not round off the **form data** it receives. It only rounds off the initial data (as in *defaults*, or *model/saved data*).

We can easily change this behavior with a modified DecimalField implementation, wherein we override the `process_formdata` method. Somewhat like so:

```
from wtforms import DecimalField


class BetterDecimalField(DecimalField):
    """
    Very similar to WTForms DecimalField, except with the option of rounding
    the data always.
    """
    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, places=2, rounding=None,
                 round_always=False, **kwargs):
        super(BetterDecimalField, self).__init__(
            label=label, validators=validators, places=places, rounding=
            rounding, **kwargs)
        self.round_always = round_always

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            try:
                self.data = decimal.Decimal(valuelist[0])
                if self.round_always and hasattr(self.data, 'quantize'):
                    exp = decimal.Decimal('.1') ** self.places
                    if self.rounding is None:
                        quantized = self.data.quantize(exp)
                    else:
                        quantized = self.data.quantize(
                            exp, rounding=self.rounding)
                    self.data = quantized
            except (decimal.InvalidOperation, ValueError):
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid decimal value'))
```

Example usage:

```
rounding_field = BetterDecimalField(round_always=True)
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/bool-dev/9e2d8440e4d50ace4ec4)